# Use axios post to access mediawiki API

Tags: post, vuejs2, axios, mediawiki

I have been using MediaWiki API for some time using properly formatted URLs, but i need to access a wiki with a required login.

I tried using fetch to make the request, and also axios, and the result is the same: the HTML page of the API, the same I would get if i just put the URL of the api in a browser.

My axios call is this:

```
axios.post('/wiki/api.php', {
   logintoken: "this. Token",
   action: "clientlogin",
   username: "xxxxx",
   password: "yyyyyy",
   loginreturnurl: "http://localhost/",
   format: "json"
}).then(function (response) {
   console.log(response. Data);
})
```

It is as if the post request is simply not made. I tested using the Wikipedia api, and the result is the same.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add a `?format=json` parameter?
Even though it is a post request

Comment: I tried that and had the same problem. If I use postman, I get the same answer. If i try, for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=clientlogin, i receive the corresponding answer, but it is as if the API completely ignores the post body. I tried an example in python and that is the only way I was able to log in correctly.

Comment: @PauloAlves what kind of error are you getting? What do you seen in the console?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it all came down to the fact that the MediaWiki API was expecting the parameters in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format, and not application/json or text/plain ones.

When I changed that, I was able to login as expected, regardless of using axios or simply fetch.

The final code looks like this (token obtained via another API call):

```
const opts = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          "logintoken": this.token,
          "action": "clientlogin",
          "username": "username",
          "password": "password",
          "loginreturnurl": "http://localhost/",
          "format": "json"
        })
      };
      const res = await fetch('/wiki/api.php', opts).
```